# Alternatives to Pulse Secure

Tags: networking, openvpn, vpn

I am struggling to set a VPN connection to our university's network, so far to no avail. Our standard method is via Pulse Secure.

The IT department provides a pulseSecure.deb file for this purpose, but I could not install it with dpkg -i pulseSecure.deb, it quits with a syntax error in one of the shell scripts they provided.

Ideally, I do not want to debug their long scripts, nor I prefer installing such an additional software. Is there a way to use a more native VPN client for this purpose or do I absolutely have to use Pulse Secure? May I not configure it as OpenVPN or PPTP through the Network Manager?

I am using 64 bit Linux Mint 19.1, am totally OK with a command line solution. The only configuration parameters the IT department provides for Pulse Secure are:

Name: VPN.UNIV.EDU

URL: https://VPN.UNIV.EDU/linux

Comment: openconnect supports juniper protocol (old pulse protocol) and recent version supports also newer pulse connect secure protocol. There's NetworkManager support. The real problem is I don't know if it's available on Linux Mint (rather than say Debian)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get my FreeBSD box connected to Pulse Secure via a combination of a rather recent version of [OpenConnect](http://www.infradead.org/openconnect/pulse.html) and a [handy Python package](https://github.com/russdill/juniper-vpn-py).

The juniper-vpn-py package requires Python2 and a handful of dependencies (listed in its requirements.txt file). You'll know you've met them if you're able to do `python2.7 juniper-vpn.py` and get back the minimal error: `--host and <action> are required parameters`. (Note that your means of executing Python 2 may be different than mine.)

After that, in my particular case I am able to execute:

```
sudo openconnect --juniper --user [username] --csd-wrapper tncc.py [vpn address]
```

and I'll get command-line prompts very similar to what I'd see if using the proper Pulse Secure client. Once I pass the various security validations it works just like it does in my Windows VM, except without the burden of Windows.